universal function to Convert a string to a formula in Google Spreadsheet
What formula can i use to convert the text present in A3 as a formula and be used in B3 to execute it.
I need to create a function in google sheets such that it should take Text (in A3) as input and read it as formula while displaying result in B3
Also, the formula should be in such a way that, if i drag it down the column, it should work corresponding to adjacent cells.

I tried setformula() function but i'm unable to proceed with google api permission which during the process, it didn't prompt me in any way to give the permissions successfully

Use the INDIRECT function:
=INDIRECT(A3)


usually it is not recommended to use per-row formula. your sheet can get clogged as each formula needs to execute several times (on every edit & every time interval & other events). while it is true that on a small scale (under 1000 rows) it does not matter, it is a good practice to process arrays with one single formula. therefore:
try this in B3:
=BYROW(A3:A11; LAMBDA(x; INDIRECT(x)))

and to make A11 dynamic, we can further do:
=BYROW(A3:INDEX(A:A; MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))); LAMBDA(x; INDIRECT(x)))


this will of course work only if your sheet is named Copy of NAVRef'
if your sheet is Copy of NAVRef you need to remove that apostrophe '

